# Scaling Rather than Moving Objects when Attached to Curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm following this tutorial on YouTube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrFHwoewoPU

And it gets to a point where I'm trying to move the tread onto the main object. The problem is every time I try to move the tread it's moving the origin instead of the object.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to move the object.

It goes from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, seems I've just figured it out and it's ridiculously simple.

Grab the tread **AND** the curve and then move.